# method setInterval works correctly in server development and integration but works once on server quality

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

The method `setInterval` is working correctly on the server development and integration server, but only works  once on the quality server.
Looking in the `console`, no error is reported.
difficult to find the source of this bug.

Someone would have an idea about this problem?

Ps: I have the same code deployed  with same libraries called on the three servers and the same version of the `chrome browser` that I use for the tests.

Here is the minimal code:

```js
//start timer
var varTimer = 0;
refreshPeriod = 5
varTimer = setInterval(readTimer, 1000);

// function to refresh my datatbale 
refreshDataTable();


function refreshDataTable() {
  var inputs = {};
  flexnetContext.callOperation('FLA_ASO_CockpitOrdersDatatable_001', inputs, successOrdersDataExecution, failureExecution);
}

var successOrdersDataExecution = function() {
  // do some process here and restart timer
  varTimer = setInterval(readTimer, 1000);
}

var successExchangerReadExecution = function() {
  // do some process here and restart timer
  varTimer = setInterval(readTimer, 1000);
}

var failureTimer = function(message) {
  //display error and stop all timer
  newMessage(message, 'error');

}


function readTimer() {   

  // stop timer here and do processing and restart timer in fucntion "successExchangerReadExecution"
  clearInterval(varTimer);
  var inputs = {};
  flexnetContext.callOperation('FLA_ASO_CockpitCheckEvent_001', inputs, successReadExecution, failureTimer);
  inputs = {};
  inputs.ExchangerID = '';
  inputs.Warehouse = warehouse;

  flexnetContext.callOperation('FLA_ASO_ExchangerEvent_001', inputs, successExchangerReadExecution, failureTimer);


  refreshCount += 1;
  if (refreshCount == refreshPeriod) {
    refreshDataTable();
    refreshCount = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code, then we can help you.

Comment: If you couldn't find, how we are supposed to find whithout seeing your code?

Answer (score 0):

this is a  minimal code:

```js
//start timer
var varTimer = 0;
refreshPeriod = 5
varTimer = setInterval(readTimer, 1000);

// function to refresh my datatbale 
refreshDataTable();


function refreshDataTable() {
  var inputs = {};
  flexnetContext.callOperation('FLA_ASO_CockpitOrdersDatatable_001', inputs, successOrdersDataExecution, failureExecution);
}

var successOrdersDataExecution = function() {
  // do some process here and restart timer
  varTimer = setInterval(readTimer, 1000);
}

var successExchangerReadExecution = function() {
  // do some process here and restart timer
  varTimer = setInterval(readTimer, 1000);
}

var failureTimer = function(message) {
  //display error and stop all timer
  newMessage(message, 'error');

}


function readTimer() {   

  // stop timer here and do processing and restart timer in fucntion "successExchangerReadExecution"
  clearInterval(varTimer);
  var inputs = {};
  flexnetContext.callOperation('FLA_ASO_CockpitCheckEvent_001', inputs, successReadExecution, failureTimer);
  inputs = {};
  inputs.ExchangerID = '';
  inputs.Warehouse = warehouse;

  flexnetContext.callOperation('FLA_ASO_ExchangerEvent_001', inputs, successExchangerReadExecution, failureTimer);


  refreshCount += 1;
  if (refreshCount == refreshPeriod) {
    refreshDataTable();
    refreshCount = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: i use methode setTimeout recursive instead of method setinterval and it solves my problem. Thanks for your attention